# How to check whether element visibility=hidden is true jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's say I got 2 elements, div1 and div2. And when I click on div1, div2 should `.toggleClass()` between `visibility=hidden` and `visibility=visible`. This works fine. But when I'm trying this:

```
if($('#div2').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
$('#div1').replaceWith('<span> Duh </span>');
}
```

Nothing really happens. If I change `'hidden'` to `'visible'` it works just fine. But that's not what I want. I know that when visibility=hidden is in use the element is still considered as visible, but shoulnd't `.css('visibility') == 'hidden'` check whether the style of the element is set to visibility=hidden? Which in my case should be true.

I also tried

```
if($('#div2').hasClass('visHidden')) {
$('#div1').replaceWith('<span> Duh </span>');
}
```

But nothing happens.

Could the problem be that when the DOM loads neither of the visHidden and visVisible classes are set? Because I only set them with jQuery if element is clicked. If that's the case is there a way go around it? And I can't use display property.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle ?

Comment: when are the snipplets shown executed? (It somehow sounds like you expect that the code would cause div1 to be updated automatically when you change the class of div2)

Comment: @subsub You are absolutely right. I added a refresh button: `$('#refresh').click(function() {...}` and after that if-statement executed correctly. Thanks for pointing out the thing that should've been obvious..

Comment: @subsub I was so confused because it worked when `'hidden'` was `'visible'`. Didnt really remember that when the DOM loads up all the visible elements have already `'visible'` style. So no need to refresh that time.

Answer (score -1):

you should try `.is()` method of `jquery` to check visibility.

```
$(element).is(":visible") // Checks for display:[none|block], ignores visible:[true|false]
```

in your case,

```
if(!$('#div2').is(":visible")) {
    $('#div1').replaceWith('<span> Duh </span>');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is Your Answer

```
    if($('#div2').is(':visible')) {....}
```

Comment: No it isn't. `:visible` doesn't work with elements that have their visibility toggled with the `visibility` CSS attribute.